# Copy file from assets to permanent location Qt + Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, storage

I'm trying to copy a default initialized database packaged in the assets folder to an permanent location in an android device. For this I hav the following code:

```
QString db_file = "/my_db";
QString path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation);
QFile assets_path("assets:" + db_file);
assets_path.copy(path + db_file);
QFile::setPermissions(path + db_file, QFileDevice::ReadUser | 
                                      QFileDevice::WriteUser);
```

And then I would go on to open the database in this new path, the thing is I'm getting the following error after the copy.

```
Copy error "Cannot create /data/user/0/org.qtproject.Demo/files/my_db for output"
```

What am I doing wrong?. Is also this the correct/proper way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you established the permissions on your manifest?

Comment: @eyllanesc Don't you have permissions by default for internal storage?

Comment: No, Android requires that you establish all the necessary permissions.

Comment: One does not need permissions for internal storage indeed.

Comment: @eyllanesc Which is? I only see the one for reading/writing to EXTERNAL_STORAGE (and are also set)

Comment: It is unclear when you get that error. Not during copy()? After it when you try to open a database?

Comment: What is the value of `path + db_file` ?

Comment: @greenapps The same as the one advertised in the error, "/data/user/0/org.qtproject.Demo/files/my_db ". I'm checking the error after the copy. In fact the database then 'opens' but It results in an empty db (and not the one in assets is not empty, I checked).

Comment: That is a strange path for a database file. It should be more like `/data/user/0/org.qtproject.Demo/databases/my_db`.

Comment: In java one would use getDatabasePath("mydb.db"). Try to find the equivalent for QT.

Comment: @Aram, did you give a try to avoid the 'path' qualifier, and copy directly to app location: assets_path.copy(./my_db) .. I remember I debugged similar issue that way

Comment: @Aram, in some references (https://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2017/01/qt-creator-include-additional-files.html)  , the path qualifier can be something like:  path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::StandardLocation::AppDataLocation);

Comment: @MohammadKanan before using AppDataLocation I was using ApplicationLocation (which I realize didn't exist for android phones) so the path was actually "" and I was writing to ./my_db it was working now it doesnt work :/. I'm just scratching my head against this problem..

Comment: As it appears from the error " .. Cant create .." , I suspect that the file is not getting copied along the package apk .. keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well aparently is a bug in Qt 5.10 prebuilt version, rolled back to Qt 5.9 and it works. Its a shame since I needed the QML translation functions.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-64103